# PROCESS macro in R: Error in process.describ3(ytmp, 0, quantile) : could not find function "process.describ3"

Tags: r

I'm running a moderation analysis in R, and using the PROCESS function produced by  Andrew F. Hayes. Although PROCESS runs ok in R, once i write the function process(data, y=, x, w, model=1), it produces this error: `Error in process.describ3(ytmp, 0, quantile) : could not find function "process.describ3".`

Has anyone come across a similar issue before and managed to solve it?

Apologies i've added the script to download here as it's quite big! http://processmacro.org/download.html

And a screenshot of my data, using variables in columns 1-7[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06kP9.png)

Comment: Hi Alice, it would be helpful if you can provide a reproducible script.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: As others mentioned, please share a reproducible dataset using the `dput` function. Here is how: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg